# How to write code in subclass to resume some of the logic in parent class?

Tags: java, java-8

I have product object and two class AsiaProductValidation and ProductValidation.AsiaProductValidation is called when region is Asia. ProductValidation is parent class which has some functions that can be used in AsiaProductValidation. I want to know can i write validate method in AsiaProductValidation to reuse some checks written in parent class

```
 class Product{
        int id,
        long price;
        String region;

        Product(int id, long price, String region){
            this.id = id;
            this.price = price;
            this.region = region;
       }

       // getters for id,price and locId
    }

    Class ProductValidation{
       public static validate(List<Product> list, int qty, int totalAvailableQty){
         if(list.size() == 0)
            return //some expceptio
         if(qty < totalAvailableQty){
            return //some exception
         }

         if(qty == totalAvailableQty){
             calculate(list);
          }

        }

        private long[] calculate(List<Product> list){
          return list.stream().mapTolong(p -> p.getPrice()).toArrat()l
        }



    }

    class AsiaProductValidation{


    public static validate(List<Product> list, int qty, int totalAvailableQty){
        // First two conditions stay same as above
        if(list.size() == 0)
            return //some expceptio
         if(qty < totalAvailableQty){
            return //some exception
         }
          //only calculate function changes, how can i use inheritance here to avoid writing above two 
         checks in this class. and also call above two checks when this class is called?

         calculate(list);
    }

     private long[] calculate(List<Product> list){
          return list.stream().mapTolong(p -> p.getPrice() < 100 ? 0 : p.getPrice()).toArray();l
        }
    }

    class RegionCalculate{

      public void call(List<Product> list, int qty, int totalAvailableQty ){
         if(region == Asia){
                AsiaProductValidation.validate(qty,totalAvailableQty )
         }
         else{
             ProductValidation.validate(qty,totalAvailableQty)
         }
       }

    }

    long[] price = {40, 90, 40};

    List<Product> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new Product(1,100, "ASIA"));
    list.add(new Product(1,110, "AUS));
    list.add(new Product(1,90, "EUROPE"));

    RegionCalculate reg = new RegionCalculate();
    reg.call(list, 1100, 500);
```

Comment: What you want is class extension. The standard practice is to create an abstract class with abstract methods that needs to be implemented or that you want extended. Then in your child classes you would call the super class method first (e.g. super.validate())

Comment: What means `return //some exception`? Do you mean `throw`? Your mixture of `static` and non-`static` methods does not work. When you want overridable methods, don't use `static`. Then, when you remove the `private` modifier from `calculate`, you can override it in a subclass and don't need to override the `calc` method.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to write in class extension. You should use AsiaProductValidation as an abstract class so that it can easily expand on the functionality of ProductValidation:

```
Class ProductValidation { //Insert Implementation }

abstract class AsiaProductValidation extends ProductValidation {
super.methodName()
//etc }
```